# Python,using dataframes how to split the value of a string in a column and then add a new column with the value from the split

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Ok. That title is terrible but let's try with an example.
Let us imagine we have soemthing like this:

```
c1         c2   
column1-x   2  
column1-y   3  
column2-x   5
column3     6
```

And i would want it to end up like this:

```
c1         c2   c3
column1-x   2   column1
column1-y   3   column1
column2-x   5   column2
column3     6   column3
```

As you probably guessed this is an attempt on rejoining the value importance after one-hot encoding after this I will make the sum of all values with the same value in c3, but for that i need to be able to check the value in c1 before the "-" to add that third column c3.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe you're looking for `str.split` -

```
df['c3'] = df.c1.str.split('-').str[0]
df

          c1  c2       c3
0  column1-x   2  column1
1  column1-y   3  column1
2  column2-x   5  column2
3    column3   6  column3
```

Comment: That is quick :-)

Comment: @Wen It only takes 15 seconds to come up with a solution. The rest is trial and error. ;-)

Comment: And it's exactly like that, thank you, had no idea you could do it like that.

Comment: @BryceSoker if it solve the problem , please accept this :-)

Comment: @BryceSoker Also, you can vote on answers if you liked them. Happy coding.

Comment: @Wen Yep done, went to make dinner before since this needs 10 minutes to be able to mark.